# How to trigger Kotlin Flow sequentially and combine the result together?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-flow

As title, I got two flows and need to trigger them sequentially first then combine the result.

```
data class User(
    val name: String, 
    val age: Int,
)

data class UserStatus(
    val status: String, 
)

fun flow1() = flow {
    delay(300L)
    emit(User("Tony Stuck", 50))
}

fun flow2(age: Int) = flow {
    val result = when {
        age > 60 -> "Over 60"
        age < 60 -> "Under 60"
        else -> "Equal 60"
    }
    delay(500L)
    emit(UserStatus(result))
}

// The code below isn't what I expected
flow1.flatMapMerge {
        flow2(it.age)
    }
    .collect {
        // here I get **UserStatus**, but I want Pair(User, UserStatus)
    }
```

I'v tried using **flatMapMerge**, but it will map to flow2 finally, what I expect to get is Pair(User, UserStatus), is there any better way to deliver this ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

```kotlin
flow1.flatMapMerge { user ->
    flow2(user.age).map { userStatus ->
        user to userStatus
    }
}.collect { pair ->
    // pair is of type Pair<User, UserStatus>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `flow2` is a function and not a variable since it looks like you are passing a parameter, why is `flow2` a Flow at all? It only returns one thing. That's better suited for a suspend function or a function that returns a Deferred.

```
suspend fun getStatus(age: Int): UserStatus {
    val result = when {
        age > 60 -> "Over 60"
        age < 60 -> "Under 60"
        else -> "Equal 60"
    }
    return UserStatus(result)
}


flow1.map {
    it to getStatus(it)
}
.collect {
    // this is Pair(User, UserStatus)
}
```

If you really need `flow2` to be a Flow and its first result is the value you need, then:

```
flow1.map {
    it to flow2(it).first()
}
.collect {
    // this is Pair(User, UserStatus)
}
```

Comment: My bad, flow1 and flow2 both are function and return a flow, but your answer is good, thx mate

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `Flow.combine(..)`

https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html